# GetFullPathNameA Returns Project's Path

Tags: c, windows, winapi

When I tried the following code:

```
char pathStr[MAX_PATH];
DWORD pathLen = GetFullPathNameA("notepad++.exe", MAX_PATH, pathStr, NULL);
```

I got in "pathStr" the current directory's path with the "notepad++.exe" at the end of it instead of the real path of the file... Am I missing something here?

Comment: *`GetFullPathName` merges the name of the **current drive and directory** with a specified file name*

Comment: I think the function you're looking for is [`SearchPathW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-searchpathw).

Comment: Oh ok... So there's an another way to find a specific file's path? lol I feel like an idiot

Comment: If the file isn't found in a `PATH` directory, you can also try [`AssocQueryStringW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-assocquerystringw) (`ASSOCF_INIT_BYEXENAME`) and also try enumerating the user and system [App Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration#using-the-app-paths-subkey) under "[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths".

Comment: I guess first of all you need to specify what you are trying to achieve. At the moment we are all guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood what the function is for. The Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamea) for the function states:

GetFullPathName merges the name of the current drive and directory with a specified file name to determine the full path and file name of a specified file.

You could try the SearchPath function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-searchpatha) to try to find an executable within the current search path from just the filename.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it:)